# How to change an item's attack damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm doing a RPG in minecraft with some friends but we don't know how to modify the sword damage with commands, we have already tried this command...

`/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:724099,UUIDMost:439684,Slot:"mainhand"}],Unbreakable:1}`

...but it didn't work.
If possible, show us how to do it in **1.16.1** .

Comment: The first thing I'd check is are you using the UUID fields correctly?  I thought some of that had changed in the last few versions.

Comment: [Looking at the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format#Attribute_Modifiers), your NBT data isn't correct, specifically the UUID.

Comment: which are the new ones?

Comment: would a sharpness enchant work? in that case, the command `/give @p diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"sharpness", lvl:20}]}` would give you a sword that does ~27 damage.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but we have another commands that depend on an enchantment pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in 1.16, the attribute modifiers have been renamed. Therefore, `generic.attackDamage` is now `generic.attack_damage`.

Then, you must get the UUID correct. The UUID is now stored as an `TAG_Int_Array` instead of two `TAG_Long`s. So instead of:

```
UUIDLeast:1234,UUIDMost:5678 --> UUID:[I;12,34,56,78]
```

Therefore, here is the replacement for *your* UUID:

```
UUIDLeast:724099,UUIDMost:439684 --> UUID:[I;439,684,724,099]
```

But there's another quirk about the system. Apparently, `TAG_String`s don't need to be quote-surrounded if they don't contain spaces and special characters. This means you can make a string tag like this:

```
MyString:HelloWorld
```

But this also means that any items that aren't valid numbers are treated like strings, *and numbers with prefixed zeros are considered invalid and are treated as strings*. So `99` is a `TAG_Integer`, but `099` is a `TAG_String`, *even if there are no quotes around it*.

Fixed command:

```
/give @p netherite_sword{Unbreakable:1b,AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attack_damage",Name:"generic.attack_damage",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUID:[I;439,684,724,99]}]} 1
```