# Why is Minecraft registering a TAG_String without any quotation marks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been experimenting with attribute modifiers on items. What's interesting is that each attribute modifier requires a UUID. So I've provided one myself by simply punching in random numbers on my keyboard number pad.

I know that in NBT, the UUID is stored in an Integer Array, which is formatted like this:

```
[I;1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And here are two of my completed commands (this is as minimal as it gets):

```
give @p diamond_sword{AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attack_damage",Name:"generic.attack_damage",Amount:1,Operation:0,UUID:[I;385638563,384738473,018492747,395785936]}]} 1
give @p diamond_sword{AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attack_damage",Name:"generic.attack_damage",Amount:1,Operation:0,UUID:[I;828748274,736284721,276385632,174612674]}]} 1
```

If you don't want to get that complicated, I've stripped it down to the bare minimums, with these commands using user-defined tags (they don't do anything but make it look cleaner:)

```
give @p dirt{MyIntArray:[I;123,345,567,789]}
give @p dirt{MyIntArray:[I;123,456,789,012]}
```

In both of the above examples, one of them causes an error. The other does not. But all I did was enter different numbers. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some very interesting behaviour that I found out while answering [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/373092/250180). I'd like to share my findings in this post. Let it be a guide for using NBT.

---

Consider a simple `CanDestroy` statement. When you think of it, it looks like this:

```
/give @s minecraft:diamond_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:dirt"]}
```

But [some](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272180/250180) [posts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/306977/250180) don't have the quotes around the value. Try out their commands, for example: `/give @s dirt{CanDestroy:[dirt]}`. Does it work?

Surprisingly, *yes*.

Apparently, you don't need need to type the surrounding quotes if your string only consists of the following characters (whitespace not included):

```
+-.0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

The one exception is if the entry is treated as a number, which would count for entries like `12b`,`512s`, and `82664`. But if the number is formatted incorrectly and would fit into the above category of quoteless strings, it *will*, even if you don't want it to. The following number lookalikes will becomie strings:

- Numbers with leading zeros: (`012b`, `04582s`)
  To solve, remove leading zeros from your numbers: (`12b`, `4582s`)
- Numbers outside the range of your data type: (`255b`, `2177548418058`)
  To solve, ensure the correct data type is specified: (`255`, `2177548418058l`)