# How do I spawn a zombie with an item from a mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to get every achievement related to the Inventory Pets mod but I need to kill a player holding a specific item from that mod, Is there any way I could spawn a zombie holding this item? I've already tried

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{id:inventorypets:cobblestone_pet}
```

but that returns

```
Data tag parsing failed: Expected '}' but got ':' at: {HandItems:[{id:inventorypets:<--[HERE]
```

Is there any way I could make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put quotes around your string:

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{id:"inventorypets:cobblestone_pet"}]}
```

Since your value had a colon `:`, which is a non-alphanumeric character and not an underscore (`_`), it is not assumed to be a string. To make the entire thing a string, quotes must be added. Otherwise, Minecraft stops reading the string at the second colon, being invalid because it expects a comma `,` to start the next key-value pair.

It thinks the colon is something entirely different, so you have to tell it that that is part of your string by adding the quote marks.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I think I've clarified it to the best of my ability, look good now?

Comment: Yes, that's great! I found this behaviour and documented it in [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374852/250180).

Comment: It works, but it still isn't putting the pet in the zombie's hand.

Comment: @grande1900 so it works or it doesn’t? Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: @Penguin Sorry for the late reply, but to clarify: There are no errors or such, but it isn't giving the item to the zombie.